# Select any element with class '' in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

how can I extract the text-value of an element with class 'test' f.e. based on the numbering?
Here is an example:

```
console.log($('ex.test')[3].text())
```

Thx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'based on the numbering'? It would help to see the HTML. Assuming you mean by its index, change `[3]` to `.eq(3)`

Comment: `$('ex.test').eq(index)` https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) that will return an element from the index of it or use a CSS selector like [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

```js
console.log($('.test').eq(3).text());
console.log($('.test:nth-child(4)').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="test">div 1</div>
  <div class="test">div 2</div>
  <div class="test">div 3</div>
  <div class="test">div 4</div>
</div>
```